# Assembly language (x86) architecture

Tags: assembly

I want to know some basic concepts of assembly language to understand it's architecture in a better way. I have learnt high level languages like C# .NET, Java, and have also been introduced to assembly language `.intel_syntax` a little.

I just wanted know some basic things like:

1.What is `.text`, `.data` , `.global` and `.code` section?

2.What kind of variables/data/code should be stored/written in which section?

I would love if anyone could answer or instead give me links where in I could read and learn.

Thanks.

Comment: It'd be to your advantage to learn assembly on the ARM architecture first; if possible. It's a bit more straight forward; and doesn't have the eccentricities found in x86.

Comment: Aye, the x86 architecture is ugly and complicated. Learning ARM is way easier (I also remember that M68000 was quite nice, but you'll have a hard time finding a nice M68k device nowadays ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.text` section traditionally contains your code that is mapped into memory for execution.

The `.data` section contains initialized data that gets mapped into memory.

I haven't heard about `.code` before, but there's normally a `.bss` section which is all zeros and is used for zero-initialized variables.

Comment: .TEXT in NASM is the same as .CODE in MASM. Don't forget that .DATA? is for uninitialized data.

Comment: @Sparafusile: Are you sure about "unitialized" data ? Because I thought it was for initialized (read-only ?) data. See [this article](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~if817/arquivos/asmtut/index.html), even though it's about Linux. The `.bss` section is for uninitialized variables, IIRC.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I've only used MASM, however, so your specific assembler might differ.

Answer (score 0):

I found Iczelicon's [Win32 Assembly tutorials](http://win32assembly.online.fr/tutorials.html) to be very beneficial. The site is a bit dated, but the information there should be more than enough to get you started. Specifically, your questions are answered in depth in the first tutorial.